# In Java, how does break interact with nested loops?

Tags: java, break

I know a `break` statement jumps out of a loop, but does it jump out of nested loops or just the one its currently in?

Answer (score 85):

Without any adornment, `break` will just break out of the innermost loop.  Thus in this code:

```
while (true) { // A
    while (true) { // B
         break;
    }
}
```

the `break` only exits loop `B`, so the code will loop forever.

However, Java has a feature called "named breaks" in which you can name your loops and then specify which one to break out of.  For example:

```
A: while (true) {
    B: while (true) {
         break A;
    }
}
```

This code will not loop forever, because the `break` explicitly leaves loop `A`.

Fortunately, this same logic works for `continue`.  By default, `continue` executes the next iteration of the innermost loop containing the `continue` statement, but it can also be used to jump to outer loop iterations as well by specifying a label of a loop to continue executing.

In languages other than Java, for example, C and C++, this "labeled break" statement does not exist and it's not easy to break out of a multiply nested loop.  It can be done using the `goto` statement, though this is usually frowned upon.  For example, here's what a nested break might look like in C, assuming you're willing to ignore Dijkstra's advice and use `goto`:

```
while (true) {
    while (true) {
        goto done;
    }
}
done:
   // Rest of the code here.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer. If you find yourself resorting to named breaks, however, you are quite possibly not doing it "the right way". :-)

Comment: Please for the sake of the people looking at your code, don't used named breaks!

Comment: Named breaks are not that bad, there are situation where they are the best choice. However, using them more often than twice per year is strange.

Comment: Nothing wrong with named breaks, especially if the alternative is multiple control variables and convoluted conditional logic.

Answer (score 4):

By default, it jumps out of the innermost loop. But you can [specify labels and make it jump of outer loops](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also break out by using Exceptions, so you can handle multiple reasons

```
 void fkt1() {
    try {
        while (true)
            fkt2();
    } catch (YourAbortException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //go on
}

void fkt2() {
    while (true)
        if (abort)
            throw new YourAbortException();
}
```

Comment: yes, but be aware of not using exceptions for implementing logic

Answer (score -2):

it breaks 1 loop . very simple. for ex:

```
for loop
   for loop
      break;
   end for loop
end for loop
```

break out of inner loop but still in outer loop

Comment: answer not relevant to Java language