# Return a value present in loop in java

Tags: java, loops, return-value

I want to return a value from the loop.
My code is as follows:

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException
    {

        long locId = 1;

        List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,-1);

            for(Location findLoc : locationList)  {
                if(location == findLoc.getLocationName())  {
                    locId = findLoc.getLocationId();

                    **return locId;**
                }
            }

    }
```

When I try to put the return value in loop I get an error saying to include a return statement.

How should I change my code so that I can return a value from the loop itself?

I want to return the new locId value which I get in the loop and not the value which I set initially as locId = 1;
I want to return the new value of locId which i get from the loop

Comment: You can return only once.

Comment: Yes I want to return a value if it matches the required value:

Comment: The problem is that every method must always have a return statement. In the code above you only return inside the loop if you find a matching result. You should have a returnstatement outside the loop that will be returned if no result is found.

Comment: Wow, 13 answers so far. People are really eager to earn some reps.

Comment: Especially since new answers are comming in saying the exact same thing that other people have written 10 minutes ago

Comment: John Snow : :) Yes I got many dupliate answers but people are helping a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various approach to this problem.

1. Use while loop
2. Use for loop with additional stop condition
3. Use break key word.

Let first create a template before introduce our logic:

```
public long findLocationId(String locationName) throws SystemException
    {

        if(locationName == null) { //Here we cover first issue. 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("THe locationName must not be null");
        }

        long locId = Long.MIN_VALUE; //We declare a default value that will be returned if none match found. 

        Collection<Location> locationList = getLocationList(); //The location can be read from another method so we are not binded to field.

        if(locationList == null || locationList.isEmpty()) {
            return locId; // Or throw an exception about invalid state.
        }


        //Place for the logic


        return locId;

    }
```

---

Typically when we do not know when we want to stop the iteration, it is a sign that we should start with while loop.

So lets try it.

**Solution 1 - The while way.**

```
 Iterator<Location> iterator = locationList.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext() && Long.MIN_VALUE != locId) {

            Location location = iterator.next();

            if(locationName.equalsIgnoreCase(location.getLocationName())) {
                locId = location.getLocationId(); // This will change the locId, so second condition will be no longer true and loop will end.
            }

        }
```

> The pros:
>   - It works
>
> The cons:
>   - Leave the iterator

We should not leave iterators, as this is error prone. This lead us to next solution.

**Solution 2 - We use the pattern for iterator instead of while.**

```
 for(Iterator<Location> iterator2 = locationList.iterator();iterator.hasNext() && Long.MIN_VALUE != locId;) {

            Location location = iterator.next();

            if(locationName.equalsIgnoreCase(location.getLocationName())) {
                locId = location.getLocationId(); // This will change the locId, so second condition will be no longer true and loop will end.
            }
        }
```

> Pros 
>    - It works
>
> Cons 
>    - It complicated, we must thing about the stop, when reading this code.

As above solution is not easy to read is should be also removed.

**Solution 3 - Why break is useful.**

```
for(Location location : locationList) {

            if(locationName.equalsIgnoreCase(location.getLocationName())) {
                locId = location.getLocationId();
                break;
            }

        }
```

> Pros
>    - It works 
>    - It readable
>
> Cons
>    - None

Conclusion is that the code should be readable. Using `break`, we point that we found the match and we do not want to progress anymore.

Fine. But what about the case when `location` was found ?

OP example we return `1L`. This is not the best choice as is very likely that this value could be used as ID.

In previous examples i have used the min value of long. This is acceptable for some cases but, still we need to validate the method result, and also document it.

The final solution present additional loop exit, that is `return` key word.

```
public long findLocationId(String locationName) throws SystemException
    {

        if(locationName == null) { //Here we cover fist issue. 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("THe locationName must not be null");
        }

        Collection<Location> locationList = getLocationList(); //The location can be read from another method so we are not binded to field.

        if(locationList == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("THe location list was not initialized"); 
        }

        for(Location location : locationList) {

            if(locationName.equalsIgnoreCase(location.getLocationName())) {
                return location.getLocationId(); //We exit from the method.
            }

        }

        throw new SystemException("Could not found location for name:" + locationName); 

    }
```

Additional note

In the example OP have `location == findLoc.getLocationName()`, the problem with this code is that we should not use `==` to compare objects types [(details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus/767379#767379). As we deal with String class recommended method is to use method `String#equals(Object)` or 'String#equalsIgnoreCase(String)'. For this example i have used the second option.

Comment: Thanks Vash for such a nice explanation. But I accepted the first among all correct answers since there are many duplicate answers :)

Comment: Vash: Well I have accepted your answer. Nice explanation like I said before.. and many different ways of doing the same

Comment: Thanks Vash for the EDIT. You really made everything very clear. Thanks again!! :)

Comment: No problem. Come back to stack any time. And share your experience to ;-).

Comment: I am always here on this site posting my difficulties. Btw, I liked your coding skills. Do you have any blog where I can followe your coding skills? The one you mentioned in your profile here is in Polish and I cannot understand..

Comment: The link in my profile is an OS web that my friend run. Sometimes I contribute there some articles but in Polish. As by my blog, I am still not ready with it to release it for public. But i can advise you the [John Skeet] (http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/) blog. You will find there many interesting article, John is also SO user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27641/discussion-between-cya-k-and-vash)

Answer (score 3):

It is because all control flows in a function should end in returning a long value.

In your case assume that there is no match in the list, so the return statement will never get executed that is why the error is reported.

To fix this you can add a return statement at the end of the function with a default value, or if your logic permits you can throw an execption saying location is not found.

Solution 1: If you want to return `1` if there is no match

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException {
    long locId = 1;
    List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,
            -1);
    for (Location findLoc : locationList) {
        if (location == findLoc.getLocationName()) {
            locId = findLoc.getLocationId();
            break;
        }
    }
    return locId;
}
```

Solution 2: Throw an exception if the location is not found

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException {
    List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,
            -1);
    for (Location findLoc : locationList) {
        if (location == findLoc.getLocationName()) {
            return findLoc.getLocationId();
        }
    }
    throw new SystemException("Unable to find the location");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because there isn't always going to be a case when `location == findLoc.getLocationName()`. Even if that IS the case, the java compiler doesn't know what sort of input you are giving your program so it it telling you that there could be a case when the function doesn't return anything even though it MUST return a long.

Just return -1L or something that your pogram can consider to be "not found" at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

*There must a default return statement. As there are only return statement which also is conditional, compiler will force you for default one.*

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException{

    long locId = 1;
    List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,-1);
    for(Location findLoc : locationList)  {
         if(location == findLoc.getLocationName())  {
             locId = findLoc.getLocationId();
                return locId;
         }
    }
    return locId; // default return value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException
    {

        long locId = 1;

        List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,-1);

            for(Location findLoc : locationList)  {
                if(location == findLoc.getLocationName())  {
                    locId = findLoc.getLocationId();


                }
            }
          return locId;
    }
```

try this you get anwser

Comment: Suresh:
But I want to return the locId value that I get in the loop and not the value of locId as 1.

Comment: you take the array and add the values to array.then return that array..try it get output

Answer (score 0):

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException
    {

        long locId = 1;

        List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,-1);

            for(Location findLoc : locationList)  {
                if(location == findLoc.getLocationName())  {
                    locId = findLoc.getLocationId();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return locId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `return` statement in your `if` statement, which is conditional. Hence, if there is a case where the control never enters the `if` block, the method would be left without a `return` value.

Therefore, have a default `return` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

In case your `if` statement didn't find any location that is equal to your location means what will happen. That is why this compilation error happens. So you must add a return statement at end of your method.

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException
{

    long locId = 1;

    List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,-1);

        for(Location findLoc : locationList)  {
            if(location == findLoc.getLocationName())  {
                locId = findLoc.getLocationId();

                **return locId;**
            }
        }
return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use break statement to come out from the loop if you do not use to execute the loop more.

**You can not use the return statement inside a for loop as this return statement will call multiple times.**

And the method demand only one return statement at a single time.
 Here `break` statement will will just break out of the innermost loop (here for loop).

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException
    {

        long locId = 1;

        List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,-1);

            for(Location findLoc : locationList)  {
                if(location == findLoc.getLocationName())  {
                    locId = findLoc.getLocationId();
                   break;
                }
            }
     return locId;
    }
```

For more details:
[Please visit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097513/java-break-statement)

Comment: This is not entirely correct. `return` will never be called more than once. Calling `return` will end the method `findLocationId` at that point in code. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is in an "if" statement, which means it will not be reached if the "if" evaluates to false. You need a return statement outside of the "if" statement.

Comment: Holy crap, when I started typing an answer there were no published answers, when I submitted 30 secs later there were 8!

Comment: yes. Even I was shocked that I got such quick replies.. But thanks one and all :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: what would your method return if the condition in your loop is not met?

You need to return a default value, and the `return` statement needs to be placed after the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 issues in your code.

1. there must be exactly one `return` for a method, but being in `for` loop, since its also a  conditional flow (it may not even run a single time) you must provide an alternate return statement. though it will return whatever comes first.
2. there must be a `return` in every flow. but since your return is in `if` condition, there would be missing a `return` statement if `if-expression` is false. You would then require to provide an alternative return statement outside `if`. (else compiler will show error)

**in your code:**
    for(Location findLoc : locationList)  {
        if(location == findLoc.getLocationName())  {
            locId = findLoc.getLocationId();
            return locId;
        }
    }
    return locId; // adding this would fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a return statement in the case the element is not found.
Trivial self-contained example:

```
public class Main {

    public static long findStringIDX(String[] myList, String myString) {

        long locId = 0;

        for (String s : myList) {
            if (myString.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                return locId;
            }
            locId++;
        }
        return -1; // Not found

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myList = new String[] { "hello", "world", "bobby" };
        System.out.println(findStringIDX(myList, "bobby"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do that.

```
public long findLocationId(String location) throws SystemException
{
  long locId = 1; // but i suggest to put -1
  List<Location> locationList = LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(-1,-1);
  for(Location findLoc : locationList)  {
    if(location == findLoc.getLocationName())  {
      return findLoc.getLocationId();
    }
  }
  return locId;
}
```