# Break out of infinite while loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I need to run an infinite loop until the user tells it to break. For example...

```
while(true)
{
   someFunction();
   Thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

As you can see I want to continuously run the function every 4 seconds. But how do I get out of the loop when I want it to stop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is nice to ask questions on forums/sites like this when you have troubles, but a question like this can be answered by Google much faster. Try googleing the headline of your thread here + java for example and you will see tons of good answers.

Comment: Vegard - thanks BUT I don't think you are getting what I need... of course I've been trying to find the answer on google for several hours but can't and that's why I'm here. Once again,  I need it to continue looping UNTIL user wants to break it. I think Junad may offer an answer but not sure yet.

Comment: if these are not answers to your question I think you need to rewrite your question, is your question perhaps how to read user input and transform it to a boolean value?

Comment: OK perhaps you could tell me this... how do I have that loop above running uninterrupted, and have the program concurrently be checking to see if user has inputted a string into the System?

Comment: make a new thread that has a shared boolean variable. for each runthru of the loop check the status of the boolean variable. but now the question suddenly became much more complex, I suggest reposting the question in a new thread with a more in depth description of what the problem is, and provide some sample code of what you have tried.

Comment: thanks yes that's exactly what I had in mind, but I suppose my issue is not knowing multithreading well enough (coming to java from c++), I'll do some more digging and start a new thread if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a static volatile variable in while and set it from other thread when you want to stop the thread:

```
while(Someclass.staticVariable)
{
   someFunction();
   Thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

from the other thread to break this loop

```
Someclass.staticVariable = false;
```

Comment: Might need to be `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

someFunction can be boolean? if so

```
if (someFunction()) break;
```

Comment: Yes, but I would at least personally much rather see `while(someFunction()) Thread.sleep(4000);`

Comment: I agree, but since the question is something he could have Googled very quickly I did not elaborate too much on best practice and just answered the question.

Comment: No, I need it to continue looping without user input UNLESS user wants to break it.

Comment: @lc s suggestion will work just fine, just make sure the function returns false once the user enters whatever should end the loop

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, you can use break; or add a boolean to your while loop

1:

```
while(userWantsToKeppGoing)
{
    someFunction();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

2:

```
while(true)
{
    if(userDoesntWantToKeepGoing) break;
    someFunction();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global boolean variable as flag, that someFunction() can change, and do something like:

```
while(globalFlag)
{
   someFunction();
   Thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **break** statement.

Have a look at *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097513/java-break-statement)* SO q/a.